# When Python frees memory?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I've difficulties understanding the automatic memory management of Python.  I know that there is a reference counting mechanism; and when the number of references to an object reaches zero the memory allocated to that object is liberated. But, does that happen immediately?  I.e., does the memory get freed as soon as there are no more references to the object? Or such objects will be flagged and their memory will be freed at a future time (perhaps defined by an independent cleaning cycle)?

More concretely, I have a program like this:

```
for param in param_list:
    result = process(param)           # `process` is a memory-hungry routine
    result_list.append(result)
```

(Actually `process` creates large `numpy` arrays and matrices.)

I ran the program for a small `param_list` successfully.  But when I increased the size of `param_list` it got killed by the kernel because of out-of-memory errors.  (Note that `result` is not a huge object, it only contains a couple of `float`s.)  This was a surprise, as I was expecting that once `process` function ends all the memory allocated to the objects it creates is freed (hence the memory usage of the program is almost independent of the number of `for` loop iterations).

When I monitor the program's memory usage, I see that the memory usage goes up in successive iterations of the `for` loop.  Is this the natural behavior of Python's memory management system?  Is there a way to avoid the memory usage growth?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but surely if you continue appending objects to a list in a loop, memory use will increase? And the list still references the object, so they won't be cleared.

Comment: Use memory profiler to understand: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Comment: Can you create a minimal example of `process()` to make this reproducible?

Comment: You can use `gc.collect()` at the end of your `for` loop, to garbage collect all references used in that iteration.

Comment: @JammyDodger You are right. But as I explained `result` is a very small object and the memory used for the list is negligible compared to the amount allocated in `process`.

Comment: @n1rna  Thank you! adding `gc.collect()` pushes the memory usage of the program to close to zero at the end of the for loop.  I wonder why the collection does not happen automatically!

Comment: @kMaster This can happen simply because `process` function is keeping references to variables used inside it and therefore not freeing the memory.

Comment: @n1ma  Thanks for the explanation.  But I am not sure if I understood.  When `process` returns all its local variables (including references to variables inside it) will reach end of their life.  So, the reference count for all memory allocate inside `process` (except the return value) should go to zero and the memory be freed.  Am I missing something?